# Read a Ruby string one character at a time (for word wrapping)

Tags: ruby, input, user-input

I know this question is a fundamental one. I am able to take user input for a string and for an integer using:

```
str = gets()
num = gets().to_i
```

But I want to read from the String(say which is in my case more than a line in length) character by character and count the number of characters from the first to the very last for every character encountered in the string. I know this can be achieved through:

> str.length

I want to count it character wise as I am trying to implement **word wrap** in Ruby, wherein say within the line width(which would be a user defined number input) I would want to print only those words which are not continuing over to the next line i.e. I don't want to split a continuous word over two lines. Such words should be taken to the new line.

Thanks for you time..!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`getc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002274) will read in a character at a time:

```
char = getc()
```

Or you can cycle through the characters in the string with [`each_char`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/each_char):

```
'abc'.each_char do |char|
  puts char
end
```

Comment: This answers what was originally asked in the title of the question, but not what was actually asked for.

Comment: LOL! I guess answering the title was good enough for the OP. Glad my answer could be of some help.

Comment: I guess my question was mainly to do with the "how to" input a character in ruby so I am just giving justice to that. I am also grateful to those who have implemented word wrap for me through regular expressions in Ruby( from their answers and I have I hope by giving a +1 at least done some justice to their effort in making things simpler for me).. but without any offence..... I was not looking for the solution on how to implement word wrap..

Comment: @mgj From your question I thought you would find my answer useful. It's also very interesting to see the very different answers from others. I like Stack Overflow because answers and questions are from different perspectives, so you get info that is more interesting and diverse than from an "official" API or manual.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out the [Text::Format](http://rubyforge.org/projects/text-format) gem. Also, Rails has [word_wrap](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-word_wrap) as part of ActionView, and Padrino has a similar [word_wrap](http://www.padrinorb.com/api/classes/Padrino/Helpers/FormatHelpers.html#M000186) method if you're doing web stuff.

Otherwise this is a linewrap sample from: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/249306

```
str = "\
I don't necessarily need code examples -- but if anyone has
ideas for a best approach to specifying a line wrap width
(breaking between words for lines no longer than a specific
column width) for output from a Ruby script, I'd love to
hear about it."

X = 40
puts str.gsub(/\n/," ").scan(/\S.{0,#{X-2}}\S(?=\s|$)|\S+/)


--- output ---
I don't necessarily need code examples
-- but if anyone has ideas for a best
approach to specifying a line wrap width
(breaking between words for lines no
longer than a specific column width) for
output from a Ruby script, I'd love to
hear about it.
```

Comment: It is attributed. See the URL?